# SonarQube use case in a multi-teamed monolithic application development

Tags: php, sonarqube

We have a monolithic application in development. Development is done by several backend teams. Our application is not tightly coupled and in general you can say, that each team is responsible for it's own set of Symfony bundles (say, top-level directories inside `src` folder).

We are now trying to use SonarQube for static analysis and overall code quality control, but I can't find a good way for each development team in GUI to see statistics for it's own application part only.

There is a project view (`Projects -> [project] -> Code`) but it's just an unusable plain list of files and problems. There are about 2000 lines in total and this is really unmanageable.

Documentation for SonarQube says, that subprojects are removed from it and apart from them I just can't find a way to make it usable for us.

Is there a way for each of our teams to see it's own set of cases and monitor quality of it's own application part only?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing out of the box in SonarQube for your case, but you could apply some workaround for this.

Create new project in SonarQube for each team and pass what sub-projects they are not interested in, for example:

```
 /k:"ApplicationName_Team1"
 /n:"ApplicationName :: Team1"
 /v:"12345"
 /d:sonar.coverage.exclusions=**\PathsToRemove\**
 /d:sonar.cpd.exclusions=**\PathsToRemove\**
 /d:sonar.exclusions=**\PathsToRemove\**
```

This way you can analyze only subset of your code. Create similar configurations for other teams.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will think it over!